# How to calculate Best 6 of first 8 months of production in spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I'm trying to find avg of best 6 of first 8 months of production for a list of wells.I have been working on it for sometime and stuck.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the Avg() aggregation.